# NFC reader commands sniffer

Tags: android, nfc, mifare, hce

I'm trying to emulate a MIFARE DESfire card on my Android phone but I simply can't pick up any commands from the reader. I have a PN532 NFC board available and different phones with NFC.

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532965/desfire-ev1-card-emulation) it is only possible to emulate ISO/IEC 7816-4 if the readers architecture works in a specific way.

So how can I pick up these commands from the reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to buy a pn532 board to run this program https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.c

In this way i could detect the readers' select package.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [OpenPCD](http://www.openpcd.org/OpenPCD_Passive_RFID_Project).

Beware that this might be illegal under some circumstances.